# Android studio no detecta la carpeta

Tags: java, android

Estoy crendo un menu en android studio, pero al iniciarlo en MainActivity.java, donde me debería estar leyendo el menu, no lo detecta y no ser porque. He probado a poner la dirección entera pero tampoco.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

Si intento borrar el menú y crearlo desde el acceso directo tampoco lo detecta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear el directorio `/menu` que contiene el archivo `game_menu.xml` dentro del directorio de recursos `/res` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asegura de volver a construir tu proyecto y verificar que ningún .xml tenga algún error.